# HTML 5 Using Rowspan on two colums in the same row

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create a table with cell 1 and cell 2 in row 1 both spanning 2 rows to get a larger header while still being in their own separate cells. Something that looks like this code

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr height="50px">
    <!--first row-->
    <th>Quarter</th>
    <!--first column in first row-->
    <th>Total Sales</th>
    <!--first row, second column-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--second row-->
    <td>Q1</td>
    <td>$5,349</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--third row--access from http://cbsnews.com-->
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>$8,349</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--Fourth row-->
    <td>Q3</td>
    <td>$22,349</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but instead of making the table row height 50 and making it just look like it spans 2 rows I want to make the code look more like

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <!--first row-->
    <th rowspan="2">Quarter</th>
    <!--first column in first row-->
    <th rowspawn="2">Total Sales</th>
    <!--first row, second column-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--second row-->
    <td>Q1</td>
    <td>$5,349</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--third row--access from http://cbsnews.com-->
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>$8,349</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--Fourth row-->
    <td>Q3</td>
    <td>$22,349</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but this generates an odd looking table.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to settle with the row height?

Comment: Hi may i know example output result you want to achieve?

Comment: One reason you're getting weird behavior is because you have a *rowspawn*.

Comment: I want to get the results I see from the first table with making the row look like it takes up two rows while actually using the rowspan command. I've tried entering all sorts of &nbsp; empty rows to try and get them to merge but I can't get anything to work using the rowspan.

Comment: You can check my answer. Hope you learn something there. And how it work,Regards

Comment: Nowadays using html attributes for this kind of job is deprecated, check my answer for a more standard code.

Comment: @justin The coding you gave me that person doesn't use any rowspan. He just add some style to make table header tall. Plus it doesn't merge any rows. Go try check it again maybe you miss something.

Answer (score 1):

Update 1.1

I already update my demo to make you easier to understand and how the rowspan and colspan work.?

HTML

```
    <h1> Without using Rowspan </h1>

<table border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>How</th>
                <th>it</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Rowspan</th>
                <th>First</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td >20</td>
                <td >30</td>
                <td  >40</td>
                <td >50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>60</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>110</td>
            </tr>


        </table>

<hr>


<h1> using Rowspan </h1>

<table border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>How</th>
                <th>it</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Rowspan</th>
                <th>First</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">10</td>
                <td rowspan="2">20</td>
                <td rowspan="2">30</td>
                <td rowspan="2" >40</td>
                <td >50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>60</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>110</td>
            </tr>


        </table>


    <hr>


<h1> using colspan </h1>

<table border="1">

     <tr>
                <th colspan="5">Hello World</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>How</th>
                <th>it</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Rowspan</th>
                <th>First</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">10</td>
                <td rowspan="2">20</td>
                <td rowspan="2">30</td>
                <td rowspan="2" >40</td>
                <td >50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>60</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>110</td>
            </tr>


        </table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sgatLLpr/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You should never use html attributes "rowspan", "border" and "height" for this kind of job, using it is a deprecate style of work. What you should do is use css to accomplish what you want.

The correct way to do it could be like this

```css
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid black;
}

table td, th{
border:1px solid black;
}


tr th {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <!--first row-->
    <th>Quarter</th>
    <!--first column in first row-->
    <th>Total Sales</th>
    <!--first row, second column-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--second row-->
    <td>Q1</td>
    <td>$5,349</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--third row--access from http://cbsnews.com-->
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>$8,349</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--Fourth row-->
    <td>Q3</td>
    <td>$22,349</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well I am currently attending college and in web design and we are going over html and this was brought up in class to row span the first row that the headers took up two rows and to only use html I did something similar in a previous class using css which brought in the height and no one in class could answer this and the professor said it was possible so I've been messing around with it for a few hours trying all sorts of non breaking spaces trying to add in blank rows etc.. but only the height could get me the results I wanted so i wanted to try and ask here if you could.

Comment: Well the thing is that, I'm not sure if 'rowspan' can be used to accomplish what you want and I understand, you are just curious about it, but is my advice that instead of spent hours trying to accomplish something in a incorrect way, use that time to improve a code in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `tr {height: 50px;}` to your css and drop the rowspan attributes.

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/bfddopzt/1/